# Fire JavaScript at keyboard entry if no field is focused

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to program a web page that lets the user use a barcode scanner to make a list of products bought. As barcode scanners normally emulate a normal keyboard entry this is nothing very special.

Anyway I found out that many people do not look at the screen when using a barcode scanner, therefore often not realising that the cursor is not focused on the barcode input field.

I therefore try to fire a JavaScript (playing a sound) each time there is a keyboard entry and there is no field focused on the webpage.

But there I am stuck:

1. How can I make the JavaScript fire only once even if 10 keys are pressed shortly after another (it should play the sound only once per scanned bar code, not for every digit).
2. How can I go about the "no field focused"-issue? Is there a way to get this info from the DOM? Or would I have to check for each field on the page whether the focus is there or not? This would be inconvenient, as the number of other fields (other than the barcode input field) can vary.

Comment: do you wanna test, if any input field is focused or if a specific one is focused?

Answer (score 1):

Below is some code, that will do the "only once even if 10 keys are pressed shortly after another" part.

It uses a timer to reset the counter after 1 second. If another button is hit within this second, the timer gets restarted, so it does not accidentally reset the counter.
I set the threshold to 3 seconds instead of 10 for testing purposes, you can change it as you like.

```
(function () {
    var counter = 0,
        timer,
        threshold = 3;


    document.addEventListener('keydown', function () {

        window.clearTimeout(timer);

        counter += 1;

        if (counter >= threshold) {
            console.log('do whatever you want');
            counter = 0;
        }

        timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            counter = 0;
        }, 1000);

    });
})()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gJC3M/2/

Answer (score -1):

> How can I make the javascript fire only once even if 10 keys are pressed shortly after another

You can't sanely do that.

Instead, set a variable to true when the function fires and use setTimeout to set it to false after X seconds. At the top of the event handler function, test to see if that variable is true and immediately return if it is.

> How can I go about the "no field focused"-issue?

Test the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target) using an event handler bound to the `document` object.

Alternatively, have a keydown event bound to each input (and make sure it calls [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation)). Have your 'no input focused" code bound to keydown on the `document` object.